# Leer datos de un array que se encuentra dentro de otro array

Tags: php, jquery, array

Tengo un array (dato) asociativo que contiene datos y otro array (otrosValores) asociativo dentro de este, el problema es que solo puedo leer los datos contenidos antes del array (otrosValores) arrojando el error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` esto en php, si lo imprimo por consola todo correcto, lo que quiero es poder acceder a los valores del array (otrosValores);
**Jquery**

```
    var otrosValores={
        val1:"valor 1",
        val2:"valor 2",
        val3:"valor 3"
    }
    var dato={
        nombre:"aqui el nombre",
        apellido:"aqui el apellido",
        rut:"aqui el rut",
        otros:otrosValores,
    }
    console.dir(dato)
    $.ajax({
        url : 'admin/controlador.php',
        type : 'POST',
        cache : false,
        data : "op=saveFicha&datos="+JSON.stringify(dato),
        success: function(resultado){
            $(".resultado").html(resultado)                 
        }
    })
```

**Php**

```
$datos=json_decode($_POST["datos"]);

foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    echo $key," => ",$value,"<br>";
    if($key=="otros"){
        foreach ($key as $key2 => $value2) {
            echo $key2," => ",$value2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en javascript no estás declarando un array asociativo, realmente estás declarando un objeto. Por lo que, al hacer el decode en php realmente no estas obteniendo un array, sino un objeto. Creo que solucionaría tu problema si accedieses a la variable `$datos` con el operador `->`. Si quieres acceder como si fuese un array creo que la función `get_object_vars($objeto)` te hará la conversion entre objeto y array que estás buscando.

Puedes ver mas info sobre esta función en: http://php.net/manual/es/function.get-object-vars.php